# Computer Terminating OpenCv Image Grabber Program

Tags: python, opencv

I Have Created a Program in Python in which it uses opencv to grab some images and save it.I have runned this program on my mac and it works fine does what i expect but on my computer the webcam feed shows and the first image when i click space works but when i click for the second time to grab images it doesnt works.The following is the error message that it shows

```
[ WARN:0] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-hfoi92lm\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (435) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

Below is my code

```
import cv2
import subprocess
from sys import exit
import os

# Code!


import time

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cv2.namedWindow("test")
cv2.startWindowThread()
img_counter = 0

while True:
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    if not ret:
        print("failed to grab frame")
        break
    cv2.imshow("test", frame)

    k = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if k%256 == 27:
        # ESC pressed
        print("Escape hit, closing...")

        break

    elif k%256 == 32:
        # SPACE pressed
        img_name = f'\\Users\\Anush\\PycharmProjects\\PelletInspection\\Sample_Images\\Sample_Image_{img_counter}.jpg'
        cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)
        print("{} written!".format(img_name))
        img_counter += 1
        

cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

try to comment `#cv2.startWindowThread()`
try editing    `cv2.waitKey(33)` instead of `cv2.waitKey(1)`